# Excel Solver solution in Python. Scipy not working

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a simple non-linear optimization project. I want to find the discount rate for future cash flows and terminal value so that the sum equals to the specified NPV. Below are some experiments that I have tried.

Both companies have a fixed cash flow of 10 with different NPV. The discount rate results should be 1.074 (7.4%) and 1.052 (5.2%) respectively. Excel Solver found the roots quickly while the Scipy returned NoConvergence.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton_krylov
from scipy.optimize.nonlin import NoConvergence


cf_fy1 = [10]*2
cf_fy2 = [10]*2
cf_fy3 = [10]*2
cf_fy4 = [10]*2
cf_fy5 = [10]*2
cf_fy6 = [10]*2
npv = [200, 400]

def mydr(dr):
    terminal_value = np.divide(cf_fy6, np.subtract(dr, 1.03))
    ev = np.sum([np.divide(cf_fy1, np.power(dr, 1)),
                 np.divide(cf_fy2, np.power(dr, 2)),
                 np.divide(cf_fy3, np.power(dr, 3)),
                 np.divide(cf_fy4, np.power(dr, 4)),
                 np.divide(cf_fy5, np.power(dr, 5)),
                 np.divide(terminal_value, np.power(dr, 5))], axis=0)
    z = np.subtract(ev, npv)
    return abs(z)

try:
    sol = newton_krylov(mydr, [1.1] * len(npv))
    converged = True
except NoConvergence as e:
    sol = e.args[0]
    converged = False
```

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs the Newton-Krylov method is (only?) suitable for solving large-scale problems. And the Newton-Krylov method doesn't converges with your initial point. Since it's a very simple problem, I'd use the general [root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root) method instead:

```
In [13]: from scipy.optimize import root

In [14]: root(mydr, x0 = [1.1, 1.1])                                                                 
Out[14]: 
    fjac: array([[-9.99999700e-01,  7.74730469e-04],
       [-7.74730469e-04, -9.99999700e-01]])
     fun: array([9.03350275e-06, 1.53610404e-06])
 message: 'The solution converged.'
    nfev: 40
     qtf: array([-9.03230997e-06, -1.54310211e-06])
       r: array([ -4128.02172068, -37514.05364792,  19083.3896212 ])
  status: 1
 success: True
       x: array([1.07391362, 1.05176871])
```

If needed, you can set the used solver by the `method` option (Note the different initial point):

```
In [15]: root(mydr, x0 = [1.05, 1.05], method="krylov")                                              
Out[15]: 
     fun: array([3.97903932e-13, 1.68824954e-11])
 message: 'A solution was found at the specified tolerance.'
     nit: 7
  status: 1
 success: True
       x: array([1.07391362, 1.05176871])
```

Comment: Thanks tons. It's working now. Replacing with root improved the accuracy a lot. I found "root" results tend to be more accurate when I run with fewer companies. A cheap solution would be to use previous output as guess for your next run, and repeat the process for multiple times to ultimately get the most accurate results.